# How can I express this custom loss function in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, pytorch

I've got a loss function that fulfills my needs, but is only in PyTorch. I need to implement it into my TensorFlow code, but while most of it can trivially be "translated" I am stuck with a particular line:

```
y_hat[:, torch.arange(N), torch.arange(N)] = torch.finfo(y_hat.dtype).max  # to be "1" after sigmoid
```

You can see the whole code in following and it is indeed pretty straight forward except for that line:

```
def get_loss(y_hat, y):
 # No loss on diagonal
 B, N, _ = y_hat.shape
 y_hat[:, torch.arange(N), torch.arange(N)] = torch.finfo(y_hat.dtype).max  # to be "1" after sigmoid

 # calc loss
 loss = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_hat, y)  # cross entropy

 y_hat = torch.sigmoid(y_hat)
 tp = (y_hat * y).sum(dim=(1, 2))
 fn = ((1. - y_hat) * y).sum(dim=(1, 2))
 fp = (y_hat * (1. - y)).sum(dim=(1, 2))
 loss = loss - ((2 * tp) / (2 * tp + fp + fn + 1e-10)).sum()  # fscore

return loss
```

So far I came up with following:

```
def get_loss(y_hat, y):
 loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()(y_hat,y)  # cross entropy (but no logits)


 y_hat = tf.math.sigmoid(y_hat)

 tp = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(y_hat, y),[1,2])
 fn = tf.math.reduce_sum((y - tf.multiply(y_hat, y)),[1,2])
 fp = tf.math.reduce_sum((y_hat -tf.multiply(y_hat,y)),[1,2])
 loss = loss - ((2 * tp) / tf.math.reduce_sum((2 * tp + fp + fn + 1e-10)))  # fscore

return loss
```

so my questions boil down to:

- What does `torch.finfo()` do and how to express it in TensorFlow?
- Does `y_hat.dtype` just return the data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. What does torch.finfo() do and how to express it in TensorFlow?

`.finfo()` provides a neat way to get machine limits for floating-point types. This function is available in [Numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.finfo.html), [Torch](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensor_attributes.html) as well as [Tensorflow experimental](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/experimental/numpy/finfo?hl=pt-br.Android%207%200%20NougatVs%20Android%206%200%20MarshmallowAndroid%207%200%20Nougat%20And%20Android%206Nougat).

`.finfo().max` returns the largest possible number representable as that dtype.

NOTE: There is also a `.iinfo()` for integer types.

Here are a few examples of `finfo` and `iinfo` in action.

```
print('FLOATS')
print('float16',torch.finfo(torch.float16).max)
print('float32',torch.finfo(torch.float32).max)
print('float64',torch.finfo(torch.float64).max)
print('')
print('INTEGERS')
print('int16',torch.iinfo(torch.int16).max)
print('int32',torch.iinfo(torch.int32).max)
print('int64',torch.iinfo(torch.int64).max)
```

```
FLOATS
float16 65504.0
float32 3.4028234663852886e+38
float64 1.7976931348623157e+308

INTEGERS
int16 32767
int32 2147483647
int64 9223372036854775807
```

If you want to implement this in tensorflow, you can use `tf.experimental.numpy.finfo` to solve this.

```
print(tf.experimental.numpy.finfo(tf.float32))
print('Max ->',tf.experimental.numpy.finfo(tf.float32).max)  #<---- THIS IS WHAT YOU WANT
```

```
Machine parameters for float32
---------------------------------------------------------------
precision =   6   resolution = 1.0000000e-06
machep =    -23   eps =        1.1920929e-07
negep =     -24   epsneg =     5.9604645e-08
minexp =   -126   tiny =       1.1754944e-38
maxexp =    128   max =        3.4028235e+38
nexp =        8   min =        -max
---------------------------------------------------------------

Max -> 3.4028235e+38
```

#### 2. Does y_hat.dtype just return the data type?

YES.

In torch, it would return `torch.float32` or something like that. In Tensorflow it would return `tf.float32` or something like that.

Comment: thank you. so basically the line sets all diagonal elements to the maximum of the datatype? And the code just returns that value. Since tensorflow seems to be only using tf.float32 can I safely just use tf.float32.max instead of finfo and dtype?

Comment: correct, if you are sure that dtype is float32. then `tf.float32.max` will give same result.

Comment: Setting it to the max value will give a value of 1 over the diagonal after `sigmoid`. I think thats what they are trying to do in the first loss function.

Comment: So do you know why it wasn't just `y_hat[:, torch.arange(N), torch.arange(N)] = 1` in the PyTorch implementation?