# Softmax of array with zero and non-zero values results in array with only non-zero values

Tags: python, tensorflow, softmax

I have an array with some values that are zero and some that are non-zero. Then I apply a softmax, I want all non-zero values add up to 1. But after the softmax, all values are non-zero and add up to 1.

Here's what I'm trying to do:
I have some values

```
score[0]

<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 48), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 2.405819  , 27.748499  , 16.080362  ,  8.780167  , 16.615538  ,
        19.353844  , 19.497992  , 16.051327  ,  5.4946175 , 15.927819  ,
        11.512515  , 19.716702  , 15.100697  , 26.370419  , 21.838608  ,
        10.650975  ,  9.212484  , 17.439907  , 14.322778  , 12.001259  ,
        10.433163  , 10.011807  , 15.847178  , 18.343014  , 26.086296  ,
        26.723047  , 17.28703   , -0.7059817 , 26.380203  , 21.49808   ,
        14.828656  , 13.711437  , 19.565845  ,  5.9418716 , 12.614753  ,
        29.56828   ,  1.1372657 , 25.873251  , 36.031494  , -7.397362  ,
        12.691793  ,  4.3349338 , 15.1586275 , 14.650254  , 14.632486  ,
        18.829857  , 21.885925  ,  0.56010276]], dtype=float32)>
```

and a mask

```
mask_test[0]

<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 48), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 1, 1]])>
```

I multiply the values with the mask

```
score = tf.multiply(score, tf.cast(mask_test, tf.float32))
score[0]

<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 48), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        , -0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , -0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        18.829857  , 21.885925  ,  0.56010276]], dtype=float32)>
```

That works fine. Now I want to add a softmax, so that **all non-zero** values add up to 1. The 0 should stay 0.

```
attention_weights = tf.nn.softmax(score, axis=-1)
attention_weights[0]

<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 48), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10,
        2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10,
        2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10,
        2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10,
        2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10,
        2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10,
        2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10,
        2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10,
        2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10,
        2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10,
        2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10, 2.9859784e-10,
        2.9859784e-10, 4.4956207e-02, 9.5504379e-01, 5.2280064e-10]],
      dtype=float32)>
```

And the result are all non-zero values. I guess that is from the exponential in the softmax. Is there a way to achieve this with the softmax or is there another way? The mask is not always the same.

thanks in advance

Comment: If you look at the [definition of softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function), the numerator is e^zi. That will not be zero unless the input is -infinity.

Comment: I have updated my answer, check it out

Comment: This is a standard-issue with using softmax for anything other than a relative estimation. In order to get a 0 as output from softmax, you will need to pass a very very small number (like the machine limit for float64), instead of 0. Check my answer for details.

Comment: thank you all for your comments. I'm using the custom_soft_max now and it works great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Softmax does not work that way. Take a look at the formula of softmax

[image: softmax]

You would need to define a custom function for this.

A simple way of doing this would be:

```
def custom_soft_max(arr):
    non_zero_indices = np.where(arr != 0)
    arr[non_zero_indices] = tf.exp(logits) / tf.reduce_sum(tf.exp(logits), axis)
    return arr
```

This will exclude all the indices that have a corresponding value of 0, and then perform softmax on only the non-zero indices.

Answer (score 0):

#### No need for a custom softmax.

`Softmax()` still operates on `0.0` values and returns a `non-zero` value as mathematically expected ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function)).

The only way to get a zero output from a `softmax()` is to pass a **very small float value**. If you set the masked values to the minimum possible machine limit for `float64`, `Softmax()` of this value will be zero.

To get machine limit on float64 you need `tf.float64.min` which is equal to `-1.7976931348623157e+308`. More info about machine limits on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65657086/how-can-i-express-this-custom-loss-function-in-tensorflow/65658222#65658222).

Apply this after your `tf.multiply()` and before using softmax to change the zeros to the min machine limit for float64, and softmax will mark them as 0 -

```
#Keep score where not 0, else replace by machine limit
tf.where(score!=0, score, tf.float64.min) #<----
```

Where, `tf.float64.min` gives the tf (and numpy) machine limit for float64.